# How to emit data to DIRECT PARENT only in Vue 2.0?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, eventemitter

I have a reusable child component `SizeSelector` and it has been used under 2 components served for different purposes.

In `SizeSelector`

```
    onSizeSelectionChanged() {
        if (this.isMultiSelectable === false) {
            this.selectedVariants = [this.selectedVariant];
        }

        this.$emit('update', this.selectedVariants);
    }
```

Under component A:

```
<product-size-form :product="product" @update="selectedVariant = $event[0]"></product-size-form>
```

Under component B:

```
                <product-size-form
                    :product="product"
                    :is-multi-selectable="true"
                    @update="selectedVariants = $event; log($event, 'modal')">
                </product-size-form>
```

My problem is when I click and change the `selectedVariants` in `B` it emited to `A`. How to fix it? I seems the event got emitted globally

---

Update

It sounds crazy and it is.

This one is not working

```
            <div class="product-form">
                <product-size-form
                    :product="product"
                    :is-multi-selectable="true"
                    @update="selectedVariants = $event; log($event, 'modal')">
                </product-size-form>
            </div>
```

And this one works completely fine

```
            <div class="product-form-wow-this-is-working-wtf">
                <product-size-form
                    :product="product"
                    :is-multi-selectable="true"
                    @update="selectedVariants = $event; log($event, 'modal')">
                </product-size-form>
            </div>
```

Comment: I doubt the event is being emitted 'globally'. Use some logging to establish whether that is actually happening. More likely you're sharing the same object between the two components so that changes to one impact the other. Something akin to this, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function, though it may be a different object that is being shared in your case.

Comment: @skirtle Nothing is shared in my case. I found the root cause and think it is a bug in Vue 2. The root cause I tried to style `SizeSelector` the same way as component A in B by putting the same CSS class in B. This is the cause.

Comment: You don't have JS code that tries to grab elements using selectors do you? It's difficult to speculate from the code you've provided but I would be very surprised if this were a Vue bug.

Comment: Try calling methods rather than inlining the code inside the template for the update event. You will find out what is wrong. AFAIK Emit is for DIRECT PARENT only. You have to re-emit to pass it further up the chain.

Comment: @sureshvv How? This in Component A and B's mounted method?
`this.$on('update', (...args) => { console.log(args); });` This is not working

Comment: I meant use v-on:update="update_event" and then define the method update_event(selectedVariants). Your $event seems hoaky to me.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you have 2 options:
1)Just change the names of your events, call one "update" (not particularly descriptive), and the other "update2" or anything except "update".
2)The other thing you can do is work react style i.e. instead of emitting an event pass in a prop with a callback function that does something in the parent.
Like it was pointed out this *should not* be happeing events are not supposed to be emitted globally.